# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null with a proper file

Tags: android, decode, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to get the simple `decodeFile` working and I'm loosing my mind.

The below code returns `null` while the logcat says: `D/skia﹕ --- decoder->decode returned false`
Aldo sometimes it manages to work (**one out of mby 50 times**).

```
try {
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inDither = true;
        opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        canvasBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath(), opt);

    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trace: " + e);

        System.gc();

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying again");
            canvasBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trace: " + e2);
            Log.d(TAG, "Out of memory!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
```

The File **is defined** and getAbsolutePath returns `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2015-07-28-16-18-56.png`

The File is basically a screenshot taken on the phone, it can be opened just fine on gallery apps and pc so it's **not corrupt**.

If for some reason this just isn't gonna work is there any custom libraries with their own decoders? I've tried a couple libraries but they all seem to use the same decodeFile.

I'm testing on nexus 4 so the image is 760p.

Comment: There is nothing returned in that code to begin with. What would be false then?

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "Trace: " + e);`. That will not even compile.

Comment: @greenapps It needs to set a bitmap from a file, the Log tag compiles on my side, check imports.

Comment: Indeed it compiles i see now. But you would want to use `e2` there instead of `e`. But nothing in your code that returns false. Please explain. BitmapFactory.decodeFile will return a Bitmap or null. But never false.

Comment: @greenapps ok, I know it's suppose to return 'null' but that 'false' return is copied from logcat so it does return 'false'. The only reason I've seen returning false on the internet is a CMYK color space but my screenshot can't be CMYK

Comment: `that 'false' return is copied from logcat`. Please show that complete line. Are you logging that? Wel maybe a decoder somewhere returns false but decodeFile() will return null then. Check with `if ( canvasBitmap==null)`. So the subject of your post is wrong.

Comment: Have you ever got a `OutOfMemoryError`? You did not report that. You should do such things.

Comment: Yeah, it's my bad, I named the question wrong. The decodeFile does return null and the console says false. I'll edit the question. And I've never got the OutOfMemory, I've even tried running the code on new thread and it generated the same problem. I've added the if() with system.gc and another decodeFile to retry after the first fails but with no success

Comment: Retrying makes no sense. Because decodeFile will return null if there is not enough memory available to build up the Bitmap. You willl get no other warning then the return value null. So just check for null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by adding a `while` loop with an `if else`

The following code:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opt.inDither = true;
            opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            int i = 0;
            while (canvasBitmap == null && ++i < 99) {

                System.gc();

                Log.d(TAG, "Trying again: " + i);
                canvasBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath(), opt);
            }
```

It seems to be quite inefficient but works, I'm also running it outside main thread so it's not gonna cause any not responsive behavior.

Comment: What was your problem exactly? This code makes no sense to me. For  one file you will call decodeFile() up to 40 times in the hope it will do it finally? You should just stop as soon as it returns null;

Comment: `while ( canvasBitmap == null && ++i < 40 )`.

Answer (score 0):

Retrying `decodeFile()` makes no sense. Because `decodeFile()` will return null if there is not enough memory available to build up the Bitmap. You willl get no other warning then the return value null. So just check for null; –

Comment: Ok, so I've kinda solved it by making a while loop with an if else checking the bitmap. And I've made the while loop run for 50 times before failing. But there's gotta be a better way, right? At the end the app takes up 15mb and I cannot compromise on the quality because of the apps purpose. And it can still fail sometimes, even with 50 tries.

Comment: You coud add a.`canvasBitmap.recycle();` after use; `15mb` ? You mean 15MB?

Comment: yeah 15MB, I will add recycle after the code is done indeed but I'm still a bit afraid of old device compatibility. Aldo old devices have less resolution as well, hence smaller images.

Comment: Smaller images would not be a problem i think. Bigger images would though.